# I used the Material Forms module, yesterday after trying to launch the project, I get an ImportError error: "No module named material"

Tags: django

I used the Material Forms module, yesterday after attempting to launch the project, I get an ImportError error: "No module named material" What happened?

Comment: `pip install django-material` doesn't help ?

Comment: doesn't help, module installed

Comment: Did you included in your installed apps?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'material',

Comment: all working fine, but yesterday, I ran into this problem

Comment: @Pavel did you change python env from 3.7 to something else from yesterday?

Comment: No changes, Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my fault. The Project Interpreter points to the correct virtual environment, and another virtual environment was specified in the Run Configuration (although there is a matrial). When I fix the settings in the Run Configuration, everything began to work fine.